# How to find location of each word in a folder?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a program that saves all words and their locations in given folder's files. For example, there is a method `wordLoc(File folder)` which takes a parent folder as a parameter. I did traversing of parent folder using recursive approach.

Then I'm trying to save location of every word in `TreeMap<String, Treeset<WordLocation>>`, where key is word, and value is set of **WordLocation** objects:

WordLocation is a class with fields path, row, column:

```
public class WordLocation {
    private String path;
    private int row;
    private int column;
    
    public WordLocation(String path, int row, int column) {
        this.path = path;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }
}
```

My method looks as follows:

```
private void wordLoc(File file) throws IOException {
        if(file.isFile()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int ch;
            int row = 1, column = 0;
            String word = "";
            do {
                ch = br.read();
                column++;
                if(ch == '\n'){
                    row++;
                    column = 0;
                } else if(isValid((char)ch)) {
                    word += (char)ch;
                } else {
                    if (word.length() > 0) {
                        WordLocation location = new WordLocation(file.getPath(), row, column-word.length());
                        // MAPPING OF WORD AND LOCATION GOES HERE                  
                        word = "";
                    }
                }
            } while (ch != -1);

            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Helper method here `isValid(char ch)` just checks whether my char is valid (alphanumeric values):

```
private boolean isValid(char ch) {
    if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {
        return true;
    } else if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope, DS I chose is a right choice for saving words and their locations. If so, how can I do mapping?

For example, if I search for word "Tokyo" in the folder and its subfolders' files, and want to see every location of word in files with row, column numbers, it would like this:

```
Tokyo:
filename: "ParentFolder\Cities\Cities.txt"; line:3; column:12
filename: "ParentFolder\Cities\Cities.txt"; line:4; column:31
filename: "ParentFolder\AnotherFolder\File.txt"; line:3; column: 1
```

P.S. I have an idea about the rest: to iterate through map and see if searched word equals word in map, if so I would go through all locations of given word and simply print them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to map a word, such as 'Tokyo', to a **list** of WordLocation objects. So, let's do that:

```
private final Map<String, List<WordLocation>> locations = new HashMap<>();
```

to add a new word, the job is two-fold:

1. Fetch the list for the given word, *and*, if there is no list, create it.
2. Add the newly created WordLocation to this list.

We can do that in one line:

```
map.putIfAbsent(word, w -> new ArrayList<WordLocation>()).add(location);
```

That will run the code after the arrow (`new ArrayList<WordLocation>()`), but only if the key isn't in the map at all. Then, it will return either what you just made, or the value already associated with that key otherwise, which is precisely what we want. We then just invoke `add(location)` on the resulting list.

Then to look stuff up, that's trivial:

```
List<WordLocation> locations = map.getOrDefault("Tokyo", List.of());
for (WordLocation loc : locations) {
    System.out.println("  " + loc);
}
```

This will fetch the associated value from Tokyo, and if there is none, that will return an empty list (this avoids having to then write nullchecks later). Then do whatever you want to your list. Which may be empty.

Comment: Wouldn't it still give the wrong location of a word? Now it shows that all possible locations in the file, and map them to every word. And when I lookup Tokyo, it does show all possible location.

Comment: your 'find words' code is somewhat suspect, but your question wasn't about that, it's about how to do the mapping. The fact that your 'find words' code is buggy is probably best left to another question.

Comment: Don't know I sort of asked "How to find location of each word in a folder?" xD. By how to do mapping, I meant mapping of the word and *correct* location. Nevertheless, thank you a lot!